# Random display of products in a category, filter , or search

Tags: random

how to show products in a category randomly, as well as when using a filter, also show products randomly by default.
And displaying Search results in a random order

Comment: In Magento 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

There is no random order option in Magento by default. Even if you choose "none" the order is not random.

Check out documentation here: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/category-products-sort.html

For random order you have to have to look for an extension or create one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank. Can you tell me the extensions that will help me with this?